# Short-cut/Bypass Spring Security 2.0 authentication using custom AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

For an existing working app, I want to provide a secondary AuthenticationProvider, probably with a [DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html). Let's say it's for authenticating a "back up" password, or a prior password that was changed due to strict password policies and the user forgot the new password. ;-)

For proof of concept, what would the implementation look like for this secondaryAuthenticationProvider that will always authenticate the user regardless of the incoming credentials? (something that returns an authenticated [Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/Authentication.html) object)

Which one of the MANY [org.springframework.security.providers](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/package-frame.html) & subpackage classes and methods should I look at?

Example config:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
  <property name="providers">
    <list>
      <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
      <ref local="secondaryAuthenticationProvider"/> <!-- new AuthProv -->
      <ref local="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one alternative password, you can declare a second `DaoAuthenticationProvider` backed by a special `UserDetailsService`, which will produce `UserDetails` with that alternative password.

Otherwise, you can create a custom `AuthenticationProvider`. Credentials check in `DaoAuthenticationProvider` occurs in `additionalAuthenticationChecks()`, so if you want to change that logic you can create a subclass of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and override this method with your implementation.

For example, if you want to authenticate the user regardless of its credentials, you can override this method with an empty implementation.

Comment: I assumed the default AuthenticationProvider compares the credentials with the UserDetails, but it sounds like you're saying "authentication" is based on whether the UserDetailService returns some UserDetails or not. Need to read up on the docs...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should just create your own **UserDetailsService** that has this behavior - that would be by far the easiest way to do it.